# Order statistics algorithm number of the elements that has been taken to do the process

Tags: algorithm, procedure, pseudocode

I read order statistics from the book `The Design and Analysis of Computer Algorithms", by Aho, Hopcroft, Ullman, Addison-Wesley`

*Algorithm 3.6*. Finding the kth smallest element.

The procedure is as follows:

```
procedure SELECT(k, S):

1.  if |S| < 50 then
    
        begin

2.          sort S:

3.          return kth smallest element in S
    
        end

    else
   
        begin

4.          divide S into L|S|/5 J sequences of 5 elements each  *lower bound*

5.          with up to four leftover elements:

6.          sort each 5-element sequence;

7.          let M be the sequence of medians of the 5-element sets;

8.          m <- SELECT(||M|/2|, M);      *Upper bound*

9.          let S1, S2 , and S3 be the sequences of elements in S less
            than, equal to, and greater than' m, respectively;

10.         if |S_1|>= k then return SELECT(k_1, S_1)

            else ,

11.         if (|S_1| + |S_2| >= k) then return m

12.         else return SELECT(k- |S_1| - |S_2|, S_3)

        end
```

In line number 1. Why we consider |S|<50?  If |S| > 50 does this algorithm work?

In line number 4, Why we divide |S|/5? What if we divide |S|/4 or |S|/6?

If anyone clarify my doubts that would be great help. Thank you.

Comment: You have to switch to some other approach at SOME step (else endless recursion), and it is expensive enough that 50 is a reasonable cutoff.

Answer (score 1):

**Long version**: I recommend you to read *Introduction to Algorithms* (Cormen), 3rd edition, Section 9.3, where they explain with full details selection in worst-case linear time (you can find the math there).

**Short version**: About why to pick |S| < 50 which can be seen as an arbitrary number. It is chosen that way to satisfy function's big O calculation (as n<sub>0</sub>) according to split size in step 4 (current size is 5, but can be 4, 6 as you stated or any other fixed positive number, it will appear as a constant on big O calculation T(n) <= T(n/5) + T(7n/10 + 6) + O(n) [from *Introduction to Algorithms*]).

Comment: Can you please explain  your short version more elaborately?

Comment: It will be reproducing what its on the book. Essentially, when proving big O you need to find c and n_0, choosing n_0 (S) depends ultimately on the choice of c which depend on the amount and size of subproblems (this case was 5, if you choose another number then c and n_0 will change). You need to do the maths (or read the demonstration) in order to realize why S=50 (it was because S=50>n_0).